# Access to a array wont work

Tags: php

actually i dont understand why i get no access to the values of a array.

if i print a array i get this result

```
print_r($e)

    Array
    (
        [FIELDNAME1] => MYTEXT
        [FIELDNAME2] => MYTEXT2
    )
```

now i want to access the field directly with

```
  echo"Element 0".$e[0]."<br>";
  echo"Element 1".$e[1]."<br>";
```

Under `$e[0]` and `$e[1]` I get no response (empty/nothing).

Why I can't get access to `$e[0]` etc.?

Is there any way to get access with 0/1/2... for this array, background is that i dont know the names of the elements, so i have to access with 1 and 2.

Comment: The indexes are not `0`, `1`. They are `FIELDNAME1` & `FIELDNAME2`. Try `$e['FIELDNAME2']`

Comment: Is there any way to get access with 0/1/2... for this array, background is that i dont know the names of the elements, so i have to access with 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Because your array is associative. You'd access values by their associated key:

```
echo"Element 0".$e['FIELDNAME1']."<br>";
echo"Element 1".$e['FIELDNAME2']."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have an associative array here, where the array keys are FIELDNAME1 and FIELDNAME2 and not 0, 1 like you stated.

This will work:

```
echo"Element 0".$e['FIELDNAME1']."<br>";
echo"Element 1".$e['FIELDNAME2']."<br>";
```

Or if you want to loop through your array, try this:

```
foreach ($e as $k => $v) {
    echo "Element $k : ".$v."<br>";
}
```

Comment: `$k` will be `FIELDNAME1` & `FIELDNAME2`

Comment: normaly i can get access to a associative array with 0,1,2, too  or i'm wrong?

Comment: Here, the keys are not 0, 1, 2... They are `FIELDNAME1, FIELDNAME2` as I can see.

Comment: why sometime work both way, and why it wont work in this case?